# UIButton label will not update

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, ios6

I have a UIButton which says "complete".
My UIButton resides in a UIView which I insert into a tableview.
However, I also want to update the UIButton's label to say "Incomplete" when the user taps the button.
The button label does not update!
How can you set the button's label?
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you want the button title to change, use the following:

```
UIButton *myButton;
//
//
//
[myButton setTitle:@"Incomplete" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: just curious, why would it be not refreshed if i use following way?
    mybutton.titleLabel.text = @"Try Again";

Comment: I believe you need to use the "forState" method when using buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call setTitle:forState http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIButton/setTitle:forState:

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
if([[[button titleLabel] text] isEqualToString:@"complete"]){
   [button setTitle:@"Incomplete" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   // do some stuff
}
```